# Eliminate cause of crash - if rooted on host

Tags: windows-xp, debug

Is there a way to pin down **the moments** (e.g., 15 seconds) just before a program crashes on windows-xp-sp3?

It would be interesting to inspect applications and executables and their communication and/or files being accessed - like a log of what was going on right before a program crashed? I've been messing around with *process explorer* but I can't extract anything useful.

The program itself is closed source. But it would be nice if module or code lines could be spit out.

I want to eliminate any operating system or host related issues related to the crash. This would help developers to concentrate on eliminating the cause if it is program related.

It is about me crashing PDF-XChange Viewer on my computer and them not being able to reproduce the crash. The story is discussed [here](http://www.tracker-software.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=11177)

Answer (score 2):

You will never get actual code lines out because the OS does not deal in code lines. It is dealing in byte code. You can use [Process Monitor (Procmon)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to monitor I/O requests. This may give you some insight and it will tell you what modules are loaded.