# Howto analyze dump files

Tags: windows-xp, crash, debug, dump

PDF-XChange Viewer keeps crashing on my Windows XP sp3 and I'm investigating the reason. Since I don't have the sources and the support team could not reproduce my error, I decided on debugging it on Windows...with not so much success. I'm no expert and don't really know how to analyze the dump files I created. They are downloadable from the links below. The story is documented [here](http://www.tracker-software.com/forum3/viewtopic.PHP?f=35&t=11177), [here](http://www.tracker-software.com/forum3/viewtopic.PHP?f=35&t=11303), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21335/vim-PDF-xchange-pdflatex-tex-live-2010-Windows-XP-pdfsync), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22033/pdftex-miktex-tex-live-2010-version-difference), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22039/texlive-2010-manual-uninstall-on-Windows), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22037/texlive-2011-Windows-XP-installation), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/300753/PDF-xchange-viewer-pdflatex-Windows-XP), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/306545/eliminate-cause-of-crash-if-rooted-on-host), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/308856/Windows-XP-Pro-sp3-crashes-when-running-PDF-xchange-viewer). You don't need to read through them all - basically it tells about the experimental option for PDF-XChange Viewer to refresh a document that is changed while loaded, since it used to be locked and the consequences of this on my clean Windows XP sp3.

[adplus dump file](http://igtuvf.cjoint.net/)

[Dr Watson dump file](http://jmv0ig.megadl.fr/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft used to have a webcast video by Mark Russinovich, one of the authors of the Windows Internals book. I'm not sure if they still provide it for free, but [you can see it on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSeNWvjhBfg&feature=plcp&context=C4eba063VDvjVQa1PpcFNVP7S66MnXcXcNQp3Br6G4a9OHHNkycRg=).

It's basically a quick intro to the tools (mostly Sysinternals + WinDebug) and techniques outlined in the Windows Internals book. It should get you going, and you can dig up more info on the Sysinternals website.

Answer (score 1):

I know a tool called [DebugView for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) that you can use to do it.